# Which of these sentences best describes the equivalence between mass and energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, mass-energy

> Which of these sentences best describes the equivalence between mass and energy?
>
> 1. mass is a form of energy.
> 2. mass and energy are two manifestations of the same property: mass-energy.
> 3. mass is energy confined to an object.
> 4. energy acts as mass when momentum is zero.
> 5. another different......

I discard "mass and energy are the same thing" since mass is the magnitude of the four-vector momentum-energy, while energy is the timelike component of said four-vector. Also, mass is invariant and energy is not.

Comment: It is not a home-work question. I am 64, too old for school.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say 5. "$m^2 c^2 = E^2/c^2 - p^2$". This is closest to your 4., but includes what happens when $p\ne 0$